# Data from two tables and joining in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have two tables with following costruction:

errortype:

```
| id | errortype_text |
```

errorreason:

```
| id | errorreason_text | errortype_id |
```

I would like to select all data from `errorreason` table and replace the `errortype_id` data with the coresponding `errortype_text`.

How is this possible?

Comment: Use the JOIN statement in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the tables have a foreign key you can do that in your model:

```
$this->db->select('erroreason_text');
$this->db->join('errorreason', 'errortype.id = errorreason.id');
$query = $this->db->get('errortype');
return $query->result();
```

Comment: While you asked this question with the CodeIgniter tag, why don't you want to use Active Records?

Comment: What do you mean with "fk"?
If you don't wnat to use Activer Records, and i can't understand why, you need to create a simple query:
`SELECT errorreason_text FROM errorreason, errortype WHERE errortype.id = errorreason.id`

Comment: What do you mean with "fk"? By the way you need to use `->result()` to get results from query

Comment: Okay i used `fk`. If i need my `errorreason.id` along with my results how can this be done?

Comment: Im not getting right results. Its printing the same amount as i have in my `errortype ` table with random text from  `errorreason`. I want to select all `errorreason` data and columns but replace the `errortype_id` column with the `errortype_text`.

Comment: I found the typo, `errortype_id = errorreason.errortype_id`. How do i bring `error_reason.errortype_id` with my resultset?

Comment: You add it to your select statement, so `$this->db->select('errorreason.errorreason_text as errorreason_text, error_reason.errortype_id as errortype_id')` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about SQL/MySQL it should be:

```
SELECT `errortype_text`, `errorreason_text`, `errortype_id` FROM `errorreason` JOIN `errortype` ON `errortype`.`id`=`errorreason`.`id`
```

This joins your tables based on entries having the same id and it is exactly the method Yan suggested.

If you are explicitely referring to PHP/Codeigniter, you have to pass this as a parameter to mysql_query to be afterwards evaluated:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT `errortype_text`, `errorreason_text`, `errortype_id` FROM `errorreason` JOIN `errortype` ON `errortype`.`id`=`errorreason`.`id`");
```